# Set JFrame to center of Screen in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, jframe, netbeans-7

I am developing a java swing desktop application 
with NetBeans and I want to set the JFrame to the centre of the screen.

from the net I understand that I can use

```
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

to set the frame to the centre 
But i am unable to insert the code into the NetBeans IDE
because both the `frame.pack()`
and `frame.setVisible()` are generated codes of the NetBeans 7 IDE
and it will not permit any code insertion between the two methods.

I need to to obtain the following :

```
frame.pack() 
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible()
```

Any suggestion on how to fix the problem?

Comment: Even generated code goes into some file in Java... Which file is generated by NetBeans?

Comment: coud you pease explain further am new to netbeans and java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `setVisible()` on generated code? Strange. Anyway, you can right click the `JFrame` in `Navigator` and select `Properties`. Go to `Code` and select it to do nothing. Then manually insert you code after `initComponents()` in the `JFrame` constructor.

Comment: setVisible() not part of generated to but rather want to insert it.

Comment: There's no need to do that. In the class constructor, it will call `initComponents()`, which will call `pack()`. After `initComponents()`, in constructor, call `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` then `setVisible(true)` (although I wouldn't reccomend calling `setVisible()` on the constructor).

Answer (score 27):

Properties ->Code -> check out Generate Center

Comment: This is the easiest solution. +1

Answer (score 15):

On the constructor of the frame, you have this:

```
public frame() {     
   initComponents();
}
```

You only have to put this line:   "this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);"
under the "initComponents();"

And you'll have this:

```
public frame() {     
   initComponents();
   this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

Run it, and it the frame should show on the center of the screen =)

Answer (score 4):

Follow the following simple steps:

- select the frame and go to the properties.
- click on code section and click on checkbox Generate Center.

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you got an answer to your problem, but a solution was given in the following link by Wade Chandler on the NetBeans forum.  Unfortunately the originator of the query being answered was impatient to say the least and you have to work through some angst to get to the answer.

http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic37419.html

Wade shows how to centre the GUI and what aspects of the code you can modify.

As an  aside, if you want to place the GUI at a set position on the screen then you can use:

This requires access to the Properties ->Code window as well.
1.  Ensure you select the Frame (not a component or outside!)
2.  Go to the Code tab in the properties window for the JFrame. 
3.  Locate the "Form Size Policy" label. 
4.  In the drop-down select "Generate Resize Code". 
5.  Modify the form position by clicking  the "..." next to it.
6.  Also, make sure "Generate Size" is checked as well.

If you want to place the GUI top left on the screen then use the default [0,0] for form position. To position a second GUI next to the first use [450,0].  In this case the x-value has been changed to 450, the Y-value is kept a 0.  To move the GUI down the screen then change the Y-value from 0 to say 450.

Finally, there is a NetBeans bug 226740 that can result in problems when trying to centre some aspects of a GUI. It will probably not affect you, but it is useful to be aware of it.

Regards

Derek

Comment: @DereckMannering thanks for the post will try and get back to you. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

From the link @DerekMannering posted:

> Netbeans actually generates centering logic on its own versus through
>   property use, so you won't see setLocationRelativeTo option. Go to the
>   Code tab in the properties window. Locate the "Form Size Policy" label
>   in the Code tab. In the drop-down select "Generate Resize Code". Then
>   make sure the property with the label "Generate Center" is checked.
>   Too you'll want to make sure "Generate Size" is checked as well.
>   Should be by default, but you should check anyways. Now, that will
>   work best for JFrame or Frame extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Within the Netbeans Designer area, choose your JFrame, go to code.

Within code, change Form Size Policy to "Generate Resize Code"

Then choose the Generate Center Option.

Answer (score 0):

- at the constructor writing give code below will make your jframe at the center of the screen

  ```
  public ProjectWork_jframe() {
  initComponents();

  Dimension screenSize,frameSize;
  int x,y;
  screenSize=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
  frameSize=getSize();
  x=(screenSize.width-frameSize.width)/2;
  y=(screenSize.height-frameSize.height)/2;
  setLocation(x, y);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

try....

```
public class_name{
     initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(this);
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation as to how this solves the question.

Answer (score 0):

in order to make sure that jframe is at the center in netbeans follow the instructions :

right click on jframe --> properties -->

now turn on the  :
generate center option
and make sure that
form size property --> generate resize code